# PHP adding JavaScript elements dynamically issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, element

I'm having a little issue adding JavaScript/Jquery elements dynamically in a PHP file due to the ' and " issue.

So, I echo the HTML code using:

```
<?php
     $entryId = $_GET['entryId'];
     echo '
     <!doctype html>
     <html lang="en">
     <head>
```

When adding elements dynamically I'm using the following:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "getDriverDVLAChecks.php",
        data: {ni: ni},
        dataType : "text",
        success: function(data)
        {
         var arr = data.split("##");
         for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) 
         {
          var tmp = arr[i].split("#-");
          var tile = "<div class="font-icon-list col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-xs-6"><div class="font-icon-detail"><a href="tmp[1]" target="_blank"><img src="pdf.png" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" /></a><a href="tmp[1]" target="_blank" class="software">tmp[0]</a></div></div>"; 
          $("#dvlaCheckRow").append(tile);
         }
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          console.log(errorThrown);
        }
});
```

I'm having an issue with the following line:

```
var tile = "<div class="font-icon-list col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-xs-6"><div class="font-icon-detail"><a href="tmp[1]" target="_blank"><img src="pdf.png" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" /></a><a href="tmp[1]" target="_blank" class="software">tmp[0]</a></div></div>";
```

As you can see I'm using quotation marks to represent the string, but when I'm declaring classes and ids to the elements, it seems to think I'm closing the string (Obviously).

What is the best way to go about doing this? I cannot use ' instead of " because the PHP file will recognise it as PHP code.

I have tried the following with no luck:

```
var tile = String(<div class="font-icon-list col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-xs-6"><div class="font-icon-detail"><a href="tmp[1]" target="_blank"><img src="pdf.png" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" /></a><a href="tmp[1]" target="_blank" class="software">tmp[0]</a></div></div>);
```

The error PHP returns: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to 'escape' the double quotes with a backslash, so:

```
var tile = "<div class=\"font-icon-list col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-xs-6\">...
```

Comment: Also, how would i go about applying variables to that same string?

Comment: Ignore that comment, i've sorted it. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use nested quotes...

Please refer [how to work with strings](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-work-with-strings-in-javascript)

You can use any of following..

```
var tile = "<div class=\"font-icon-list col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-xs-6\"><div class=\"font-icon-detail\"><a href=\"tmp[1]\" target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"pdf.png\" style=\"width: 100px; height: 100px;\" /></a><a href=\"tmp[1]\" target=\"_blank\" class=\"software\">tmp[0]</a></div></div>";
```

**OR**

```
var tile = '<div class="font-icon-list col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-xs-6"><div class="font-icon-detail"><a href="tmp[1]" target="_blank"><img src="pdf.png" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" /></a><a href="tmp[1]" target="_blank" class="software">tmp[0]</a></div></div>';
```

Comment: That's the one (First one). Thank you!